# Checking if full node is running

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node

I just followed the instruction to run full node in Ubuntu using the below bitcoin.org link.
https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#ubuntu-1610
How do I verify if the full node in PC is active and running? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy way to check if your node is active and running and reachable by nodes is to head over to [bitnodes](https://bitnodes.earn.com) and use the IP address of the machine running bitcoin core (or if you are on a home network, you'll need to find out your public IP address, which can be found by visiting [What is My IP](http://whatismyip.com)) and enter it into the "Join the Network" tool. Remember that your node will only accept incoming connections once it is fully verified, which can take a bit of time.

If you struggle with getting incoming connections to work, give the [Networking Configuration](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#network-configuration) section of the Running a Full Node docs a read.

Comment: Assuming you have a testnet node, do you know if bitnodes still works?  So far it seems like it does not.